# Ember Fastboot - Bootstrap's Javascript requires jQuery?

Tags: javascript, node.js, ember.js

I followed the steps on the fastboot quickstart guide, however the only difference is that I am using bootstrap-sass.

How do I tell fastboot that it should include jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

It is [explicitly not possible](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/ember-cli-fastboot/tree/a3048f24f70f03be5ab9918b4d79dea60db30f04#no-jquery) to use jQuery in FastBoot mode. For your use case, you might want to check out the [ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy](https://github.com/lifegadget/ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy) addon, which includes a [recent change](https://github.com/lifegadget/ember-cli-bootstrap-sassy/pull/39) that skips the Bootstrap JavaScript imports in FastBoot mode (you'd need to pull the addon from GitHub, since this change has not been incorporated into a released version yet).

Related discussion:

- [ember-cli-fastboot #133](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/ember-cli-fastboot/issues/133) "Fast boot and upstream bower dependencies"
- [ember-cli-fastboot #98](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/ember-cli-fastboot/issues/98) "The Road to 1.0"

As the FastBoot README [warns](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/ember-cli-fastboot/tree/a3048f24f70f03be5ab9918b4d79dea60db30f04#known-limitations): *"Only the most brave should even consider deploying this to production."* Hope you're taking that advice to heart =)

Comment: I must have missed that, well I guess that means clients with no JS are screwed...?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Yes, clients without JS enabled will not be able to use Bootstrap interactions that depend on JS being enabled. This would be true regardless of FastBoot's involvement. Could you describe the scenario you were hoping to accomplish?

Comment: I was hoping to build the app in Ember and be able to serve a 'static' version with basic functionality if Javascript is not in-use.

Comment: I see – and what exactly did you mean by "clients with no JS are screwed"? The scenario you're describing should work (if you use the addon I linked, or another method of omitting the Bootstrap JS from the FastBoot build). You might want to check out the latest discussion on [The Road to 1.0](https://github.com/ember-fastboot/ember-cli-fastboot/issues/98) for potential caveats.